# OpenNLP sentence training example

Tags: java, opennlp, training-data, sentence

Im trying to use oficial OpenNLP website manual example to train a new model, here is the example:

```
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    ObjectStream lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(new FileInputStream("en-sent.train"), charset);
    ObjectStream sampleStream = new SentenceSampleStream(lineStream);
    SentenceModel model;
    try {
      model = SentenceDetectorME.train("en", sampleStream, true, null, TrainingParameters.defaultParams());
    } finally {
      sampleStream.close();
    }
    OutputStream modelOut = null;
    try {
      modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(modelFile));
      model.serialize(modelOut);
    } finally {
      if (modelOut != null) 
      modelOut.close();
    }
```

The problem is in the 2º line,

```
    
ObjectStream lineStream = new PlainTextByLineStream(new FileInputStream("en-sent.train"), charset);
```

The help say me:
Deprecated. Use PlainTextByLineStream(InputStreamFactory, Charset) instead.
But... i dont know how to use this constructor. I would like an example use this non-deprecated constructor using the same corpus file.

I have written the next code, using opennlp help and the 2 ways to use the train method, the deprecated and the suggested in doc help:

```
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    InputStreamFactory inputStreamFactory=null;
    ObjectStream<String> lineStream=null;
    ObjectStream<SentenceSample> sampleStream=null;
    SentenceModel model=null;
    OutputStream modelOut = null;
    try{
        inputStreamFactory=InputStreamFactory.class.newInstance();
        lineStream=new PlainTextByLineStream(inputStreamFactory,charset);
        sampleStream = new SentenceSampleStream(lineStream);
        //The deprecated:
        model = SentenceDetectorME.train("en", sampleStream, true, null, TrainingParameters.defaultParams());
        //The sugested:
        model = SentenceDetectorME.train("en", sampleStream, new SentenceDetectorFactory(), new TrainingParameters()); 
    } catch (InstantiationException e2){
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e2){
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try{
            sampleStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        modelOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("modelFile")));
        model.serialize(modelOut);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (modelOut != null) try{
            modelOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }      
    }
```

But in this new code i dont know where get my corpus data file.
Any Idea?

Comment: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=opennlp.tools.util.InputStreamFactory

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `inputStreamFactory` with your desired data file, use

```
inputStreamFactory = new MarkableFileInputStreamFactory(
        new File("en-sent.train"));
```